# Possible to do INSERT with some columns from SELECT query and some columns with specific values?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to do an one INSERT statement where some values are from a SELECT query and some from specific values?

Trying to do something like this where cust_id, rep_id are from a select query and sku_ordered is a specified value:

```
    INSERT into ORDERS (cust_id, rep_id, sku_ordered='ABC123') 
     SELECT id, 
            sales_rep 
     from CUSTOMERS 
     where cust_name = 'ABC Corp';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal must be a column in output list simply:

```
INSERT into ORDERS (cust_id,   rep_id , sku_ordered) 
SELECT                id   , sales_rep,   'ABC123'
from CUSTOMERS 
where cust_name = 'ABC Corp';
```